# Chrome Extension: How to listen for enabled/reenabled event

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My extension creates context menus after user registers which work fine, but I'm not to be able to recreate the context menu if the user disables and reenable the extension.

I using `chrome.management.onEnabled` but It only get fired when other extensions get enabled

```
    chrome.management.onEnabled.addListener(async function (info) {

     // Recreate context menu based on some data  already available in storage
     
    });
```

Comment: When your extension is disabled it can't run any code so it can't receive the event.

Comment: So how do you think I can recreate the context menus that got removed when the user re enables the extension

Comment: You can always create the menu at the start of the script, probably.